# Increment a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, increment, zend-db-table

Is there a way in Zend to increment an integer, held in a MySQL column, by 1?

Thanks

edit:

My current code is like:

```
$row = $this->find($imageId)->current();
$row->votes = // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SAY INCREMENT
$row->save();
```

Comment: yes - after you provide more details

Comment: Do you mean Zend Framework? If so, which component? Zend_Db, Zend_Db_Table, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I offer the following suggestion

```
$row->votes++;
```

Comment: A very simple solution.
Thanks.

Comment: This suffers from a race condition between connections and is a bad solution.

Answer (score 19):

Yes there is.  Here's an example using products and incrementing a quantity field:

```
$table     = 'products'; 
$data      = array('prd_qnty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('prd_qnty + 1')); 
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('pr_id = ?', $this->pr_id); 
$db->update($table, $data, $where);
```

Comment: Is the downvote for my old answer or new one?  I'm pretty sure the new one is correct, no?

Comment: Yes, `$row->votes++;` would be the way to go.  In future it helps to show related code in your question so we can guide you to the best possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

votes++ does not protect against race conditions from other requests, that's why it is desirable to have a database solution.

For example: imagine two requests come in at almost the same time

```
1st request loads object - votes is 500
2nd request loads object - votes is 500
1st increments value in memory - votes is 501
2nd increments value in memory - votes is 501
1st saves to db - votes is 501
2nd saves to db - votes is 501 (should be 502)
```