# How write update query in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework 1.12. i want to know syntax of update query in Zend framework . My update query format is:

```
update `product` SET qty=qty+1 where uid=2354
```

what will **`qty=qty+1`** syntex in `zf1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment a column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400813/increment-a-column-in-mysql)

Comment: thanks Alex Howansky for this link.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use this code in class that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

```
$whereQuery = array('uid = ?' => 2354);
$dataQuery = array('qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('qty + 1'));
$this->update($dataQuery, $whereQuery);
```